# how to get json by retrofit if serialize is date

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a `Json` like this

```
"data": {
  "2020-05-01": {
    "tanggal": "Jumat, 01\/05\/2020",
    "subuh": "05:05",
    "dzuhur": "12:33",
    "ashar": "15:51",
    "maghrib": "18:40",
    "isya": "19:51"
  },
  "2020-05-02": {
    "tanggal": "Sabtu, 02\/05\/2020",
    "subuh": "05:04",
    "dzuhur": "12:33",
    "ashar": "15:51",
    "maghrib": "18:40",
    "isya": "19:52"
  }
}
```

how can I get the `Json`, If the object is `Date` but I must have to use retrofit

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a Map:

```
class Data {
    Map<String, MyObject> firstData;
    Map<String, MyObject> secondData;
}
```

Where `MyObject` is:

```
class MyObject {
    String tanggal;
    String subuh;
    String dzuhur;
    String ashar;
    String maghrib;
    String isya;
}
```

Comment: but how i can get the response value from Map it's look like List?

Comment: Check how to iterate over a map here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-iterate-map